# Set up two media directories

Tags: django, iis, media, watermark

I am doing Django project. I installed django-watermark from PyPI to make watermarks on my pictures.
[image]
Here you see my media directory,
when pictures are uploaded to django, they appear in Media root. Next, watermark library grabs those pictures, adds watermarks and drops them to "watermarked" folder. Eventually, pictures have to be fetched from "watermarked" directory.
Website works perfectly when debug=True, however on my server (I use AWS, IIS Windows for hosting), when I set debug=False, instead of pictures I get 404 error.
My virtual directory for IIS is set to be my Media root directory
[image] 
[image]
these are my settings and url files

Comment: Can you give us examples of the URLs that are resulting in 404's?

Comment: That library looks very old. I suspect it's a problem within that. - Edit: Not problem with the library, but incompatibility with newer Django versions.

Comment: https://studiokuzaneli.com/gallery-walls here you can see all, I was thinking about that too... However it works with debug=true? can it still be library's incompatibility?

Comment: Can you suggest any other library for that if you know?

Comment: It's not the library's issue. Your static directory (i.e. css/js) is also not working. So it's a different configuration issue.

Comment: could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 48 hours of research I finally found the solution. There is no issue with my settings.py or the way I have configured Media_root or URL, nor there is need for usage of os.path.join or anything else....

It was all about IIS, even though I have had configured virtual directories, I haven't configured their handlers. Apparently, I have had to open virtual directory for media files --> double click on "handlers" --> View ordered list --> move "static" at the top of the list, that was all.